# Any function is giving true if I type elements that are not in the mentioned list

Tags: python

```
listprint2 = [10, 20, 0, 90, 100, 101, 102, 103]

loopstartvalue = True

while loopstartvalue:
  print("the elements in list are ", listprint2)
  choice = input("please enter your element to check availability")
  if any(i in str(choice) for i in str(listprint2)):
    print("element is available")
  else:
    print("element is not available")

  continuestate = input("please enter if you want to continue")
  if continuestate == "n" or continuestate == "N":
    loopstartvalue = False
  if continuestate == "Y" or continuestate == "y":
    loopstartvalue = True
```

Comment: Formatting / indentation is critical in Python. Please reformat your code so we can see what you're trying to do

Comment: Welcome! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You are casting a `list` to a `str`, are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Change the line:

```
if any(i in str(choice) for i in str(listprint2)):
```

...to...

```
if int(choice) in listprint2:
```

If you insist on using *any()* then...

```
if any(str(n) == choice for n in listprint2):
```

...but this is not optimum